# RavenDB - Get IDs of root property within a non-root level property

Tags: ravendb

With RavenDB, is it possible to get the IDs of a property within another property? For example, if Foo has a list of Bar objects, and each Bar object has a SnuhId property, can I use an Include that gets the IDs of each Snuh property?

I tried the query below, but I get a RavenDB exception: index out of range. In this query, ApplicationServer is a root element, and it has a list of ApplicationsWithOverrideGroup objects. Each of those objects has an ApplicationId property. It's the ApplicationId that I want to get in the include.

```
IEnumerable<ApplicationServer> appServers = QueryAndCacheEtags(session =>
  session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<ApplicationServer>()
  .Include(x => x.CustomVariableGroupIds)
  // This is the line I'm trying to make work:
  .Include(x => (from item in x.ApplicationsWithOverrideGroup select item.ApplicationId).ToList())
  ).Cast<ApplicationServer>();
```

Either of these approaches *appears* to be working. Need to thoroughly test.

```
.Include(x => x.ApplicationsWithOverrideGroup)
```

or

```
.Include(x => x.ApplicationsWithOverrideGroup[0].ApplicationId)
```

If that first option is indeed working, then a property, specified in an Include(), will include the ID properties within it. Is that right?

I'm not sure if both of those are really working, but they seem to be. If they both work, I wonder if one is better than the other...

Ok, that's NOT WORKING. The NumberOfRequests is increasing, which I'm guessing means the number of trips to the DB is increasing, instead of just what's in the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, none of those suggestions worked in the question above. I think what has to be done is to include the IDs of the nested properties in the root object.

And that's what I did, and I was able to get the NumberOfRequests on the session object down to one. Curiously, I had to change this:

```
// Not using this, at least for now, because it increased the NumberOfRequests on the session...
appServer.CustomVariableGroups = new ObservableCollection<CustomVariableGroup>(
QueryAndCacheEtags(session => session.Load<CustomVariableGroup>(appServer.CustomVariableGroupIds)).Cast<CustomVariableGroup>());
```

To this:

```
// ... however, this kept the NumberOfRequests to just one. Not sure why the difference.
appServer.CustomVariableGroups = new ObservableCollection<CustomVariableGroup>();
foreach (string groupId in appServer.CustomVariableGroupIds)
{                
  appServer.CustomVariableGroups.Add(QuerySingleResultAndCacheEtag(session => session.Load<CustomVariableGroup>(groupId)) as CustomVariableGroup);
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but if you say it works - then so it be. :) One side note, there's not reason to call .Cast<T>() on every query.

Comment: I don't always understand what I'm doing either. :) I actually do have to call Cast<T>() because I'm calling it on QueryAndCacheEtags(), not on the session. QueryAndCacheEtags() returns EntityBase, not the ApplicationServer subclass.